# Flutter Provider: Using Stream Listener inside Provider to update data in realtime

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

Inside one of my Providers I want to listen to a `Stream`. For the sake of clarity I simplified the code and `Stream` by having just `int` values. In reality this can be a `Stream` from Firestore snapshots to listen to.

```
class MyProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  int _data = 0;
  int get data => _data;

  // called when app gets initialized
  void init() {
    // stream which is not updated often (e.g. snapshot listener from Firestore)
    final stream = Stream<int>.periodic(
      const Duration(minutes: 5),
      (count) => count++,
    );

    stream.listen((event) {
      _data = event;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

Is it ok to listen to a stream inside Provider or is there something I need to consider?

I dont want to use a `StreamProvider` because I have more business logic in my `ChangeNotifierProvider` which is not possible with `StreamProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider refactoring the business logic into separate components, then use `StreamProvider`.
If that's not possible, in my opinion, it's not wrong to update a change notifier according to stream data.